# Add dinamically column to mat-table and on click inline change column title

Tags: angular, angular-material

i try to build material table wher on button click I can add/remove column and table rows. 
I try to add

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'position'];
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = this.displayedColumns.slice();
  data: PeriodicElement[] = ELEMENT_DATA;

  addColumn() {
    const randomColumn = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.displayedColumns.length);
    this.columnsToDisplay.push(this.displayedColumns[randomColumn]);
  }
 removeColumn() {
    if (this.columnsToDisplay.length) {
    this.columnsToDisplay.pop();
  }
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lkmkqoeyxgl?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-dynamic-columns-example.ts)

And I get add/remove column, but I can't get inline edit. 
Is there any way to get this to work?

Thnx

Answer (score 2):

One posible solution would be show an input instead of the cell's label when you click on that cell. Then by using the ngModel directive (https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) you will bind the input's value directly to the ELEMENT_DATA array enabling you to see the changes directly reflected on the table.

In your component.html

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" 
         *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns; let columnIndex = index;">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <span (click)="onEdit(element.position, columnIndex)" 
            *ngIf="!cellEditting(element.position, columnIndex)">
            {{element[column]}}
          </span>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data[element.position -1 ][column]" 
           *ngIf="cellEditting(element.position, columnIndex)">
        <button type="button" *ngIf="cellEditting(element.position, columnIndex)"
          (click)="onClose(element.position, column)" >Close</button>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
    </table>
```

In your component.ts

```
 //will keep track of the cell currently being editted
 edittedCell = { row: -1, column: -1 };
 onEdit(row: number, column: number) {
    this.edittedCell = { row, column };
  }

  cellEditting(row: number, column: number): boolean {
    return column === this.edittedCell.column && row === this.edittedCell.row;
  }

  onClose(row: number, column: string, input) {
      this.edittedCell = {row: -1, column: -1}
  }
```